# classes from library are missing

Tags: android, shared-libraries, classnotfound, superslim

I am still new in Android development. I want to add a library (which is superslim lib) to my project. just like what the web said, I added following code to dependencies

```
compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
```

somehow, some classes are missing and I am not able to use it. for example, I want to use SectionAdapter but it's not available.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kob75.png)

I also try to add .aar file by put the file in libs folder and changed my code in dependencies:

```
compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13@aar'
```

but it's still not working. did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class called `SectionAdapter` in the [early_release_4](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/tree/early_release_4/library/src/main/java/com/tonicartos/superslim) branch. You can find it in [master](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/tonicartos/superslim) branch.

Since its current release branch is `early_release_4`, in other words, `v0.4.13`, you'd better learn to use the newest version.

Comment: I see. I was following the example and it's using the master branch. I don't really understand the tutorial provided for early_release_4. This should be the right answer, but last question: is there any way to use the master branch? or is there an example using early_release_4?